# How to get list of chats of telegram bot Golang?

Tags: go, bots, telegram

I need to send some info each hour to all subscribed chats

using `/telegram-bot-api/v5` and i only see how to get updates (messages from chat to me)

```
for update := range updates {
    msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)
    bot.send(...)
}
```

I dont understand how do i get list of chats to send them info. how to send msg to all chats without getting input message/command?